# How can I separate a vector into basis vectors?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, basis

I have the basis:

```
>>> m = 6
>>> basis = np.zeros((m, m))
>>> np.fill_diagonal(basis, 1)
array([[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
       [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
       [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

How can I access the superposition of a vector? Let's say from:

```
vec = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

So I want the output:

```
array([[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: So for each 1 you want a new row with `1` at the position that is the position in the `vec`?

Comment: Yes, basically that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a diagonal with the number of elements of `vec`, and then filter the rows, so:

```
>>> vec = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0])
>>> np.identity(6)[vec.astype(bool)]
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

This is however not very efficient if the number of items in the `vec` is large, since constructing an identity matrix takes quadratic time in the length of `vec`.

We can also work with `.diag(…)` as @AlexAlex says:

```
>>> vec = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0])
>>> np.diag(vec)[vec.astype(bool)]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Here we can specify different values, for example:

```
>>> vec = np.array([0,1,2,0,3,0])
>>> np.diag(vec)[vec.astype(bool)]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Comment: or this: np.diag(vec)

Comment: I think the np.diag(vec) would be more efficient but it gives me an m x m matrix with rows which are just 0. Can i somehow get rid of them?

Comment: @Luxamba: yes, by filtering with the `[vec.astype(bool)]` :)